# Problem with Ajax [SYS.webforms.pagerequestmanagerserver exception]

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, exception

I'm new in web development, 
I have a problem in a web application after deployment (it's not appeared in my development machine),
The deployment machine [Wind Server 2003 x64, IIS 6]

The error in IE after enable the debug mode:

```
SYS.webforms.pagerequestmanagerserver error exception has been thrown
by the target of an invocation.  //scriptresource.axd
```

The error is shown when an Ajax `ModalPopupExtender` is opened.
I replaced the popup with a simpleModal [JQuery], the exception is still appeared.

Inside the popup there's a user control and inside the user control there's a `RadGrid` from telerik contains a `RadAsyncUpload` in a `GridTemplateColumn`

**Edit:**
When I put the user control out of the popup, no exceptions.

**Edit:**
The scripts which inside the user control:

```
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="attachmentUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
                <ContentTemplate >

                   <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                           var uploadedFilesCount = 0;
                           var isEditMode;
                           function validateRadUpload(source, e) {
                               // When the RadGrid is in Edit mode the user is not obliged to upload file.
                               if (isEditMode == null || isEditMode == undefined) {
                                   e.IsValid = false;
                                   if (uploadedFilesCount > 0) 
                                       e.IsValid = true;
                               }
                               isEditMode = null;
                           }

                           function OnClientFileUploaded(sender, eventArgs) {
                               uploadedFilesCount++;
                           }

                           function OnClientDeleting(sender, everntArgs) {
                               uploadedFilesCount--;
                           }

                           function RowCreated(sender, args) {
                               var RadGrid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");

                               if (RadGrid.get_masterTableView().get_isItemInserted())
                                   uploadedFilesCount = 0;

                               // to ignore the file in edit mode ...
                               if (RadGrid._editIndexes.length > 0) // in edit mode
                                   uploadedFilesCount = 1;
                           }

                       </script>
                    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

kindly ask me for any extra information

Thanks in advance

Comment: First welcome to the Web Development family :) I wish you good luck. Second please post the code.

Comment: you can paste scripts that you use in scriptresources?

Comment: @A_Nablsi, which block? there are many code blocks.

Comment: @sv88erik: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean!

Comment: @Homam Something as <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" /><Scripts> I like to see all the code so is referent here</Scripts></asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: @Homam Do you use any webservice or similar? I'm interested in where you might get and send data ... :)

Comment: @sv88erik: No, there isn't any web service, I'm using an object datasource.

Comment: 50+ reputation that tempts me to try but I think I have to ask you to see the code closely and if I solve it I want those 50+ :), let me know if you are interested I can find some free time on thursday.

Comment: Try setting EnablePartialRendering to false in the ScriptManager tag to see the real error.

Comment: have you tried the telerik forums? its a paid product and so there will be good support.

Comment: @naveen: Actually no, I haven't yet, but I'll do, thanks.

Comment: When you swapped in simpleModal, did you use `appendTo: '#aspnetForm'`? I am not familiar with the telerik control, but does that javascript code need to be rendered in the UpdatePanel for any reason? Can you try just including that as a script block outside the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Have you tried using the telerik:RadAjaxPanel instead of the asp:UpdatePanel? and one thing more move the ModalPopupExtender popup control panel outside any update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `UpdateMode="Conditional"` on your UpdatePanel.

Comment: I set it to Always because it's inside a popup, and without it, the user control will not make any postback.

Comment: If you set it to Conditional does the error go away?  If so, you can then add "Triggers" to the UpdatePanel so that it only updates when it needs to, not every postback.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad type of exception. I suggest you to look at the EventLog first. Since the solution is running in Debug mode there should be a call stack available (among with the inner exception which describes the actual error) which might help to identify the root of the problem.

-- Pavel

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadWindow for the pop up.